# Why isnt the gtk dialog box closing even tho i use gtk_destoy_widget?

Tags: c, dialog, gtk

I am opening a dialog box then calling gtk_destroy_widget ,yet when I hit a button in the dialog box it stays instead of closing.

here is my code

```c
    GtkDialogFlags flags = GTK_DIALOG_MODAL;

    GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new (NULL,flags,GTK_MESSAGE_QUESTION,GTK_BUTTONS_YES_NO,"Are you sure you want to clear all ?");

    int result = gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog));

    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);

    if(result != GTK_RESPONSE_YES) return;
```

I have also tired doing it a other like

```c
g_signal_connect_swapped (dialog, "response",G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), dialog);
```

but this didn't work either.

I've tried changing the flags variable To GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT.

Comment: If you haven't yet associated the dialog with a parent window, you might try that instead of "NULL" in the "gtk_message_dialog_new" function.  FYI, I could not replicate the issue using your code.  Also, is this GTK2, GTK3, or GTK4?

Comment: GTK 3 . if i create a parent window will i have to manage that one too ?

Comment: It is customary to create a window which is used as the dialog widget's parent.  I thought that it would be too hard to try to go back and forth with comments, so I composed my thoughts below in an answer along with a sample program that you might review for some possible ideas.  That's not necessarily the only way to do things with a dialog widget, but it could provide you with some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

After receiving your comment response back I think I better understand how you had set up your code by defining and executing the dialog widget directly within your "main" function.  I don't know if I built the code exactly as you did, but I did get the program to compile.  When I tested it I did have a similar undesired behavior of the process remaining open even though the dialog widget did disappear.  I had to manually kill the process.

Customarily, a GTK dialog works in the context of some type of GTK application which utilizes either a window or application window.  So the dialog widget (or widgets) get built and reference the window as its parent.  To illustrate that in as simple of a manner as I could, I created a minimal code example you could test out to see the relation of dialog widget and window.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void helloWorld (GtkWidget *wid, GtkWidget *win)
{
    GtkDialogFlags flags = GTK_DIALOG_MODAL;
    /* NULL will work in lieu of GTK_WINDOW(win) below but it is customary to associate the dialog widget to a parent window */
    GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new (GTK_WINDOW(win),flags,GTK_MESSAGE_QUESTION,GTK_BUTTONS_YES_NO,"Are you sure you want to clear all ?");
    int result = gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
    if(result != GTK_RESPONSE_YES) return;

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *win = NULL;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);


    /* Create the main window */
    win = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (win), "Just a Dialog");

    g_signal_connect (win, "destroy", gtk_main_quit, NULL);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (win), "realize", G_CALLBACK (helloWorld), (gpointer) win);
    gtk_widget_realize (win);

    /* Enter the main loop */
    gtk_widget_show_all (win);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

With that, when the program is executed, your dialog appears.

[image: Simple Dialog]

When a button is clicked, the parent window will still be on the screen.

[image: Application Window]

If all you are after is to display a dialog and have the program finish, you could probably add the emission of a "destroy" signal for the window after a response is selected in the dialog box, but as I noted, GTK dialog widgets are normally associated with a GTK application which has an associated window that is closed by the user when done with the application.

I hope this has given you food for thought.

Regards.